# Way to execute scripts in MongoDB 4.2+ using mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, testing

Some of my automated tests use real MongoDB database connection, and prior to version 4.2, they had applied initialization script (which contains some indexes and constraints) using `db.eval()` command, but with the release of 4.2 `eval` got removed.

Is there another way to repeatedly setup MongoDB environment for auto tests?

(Using embedded Mongo is a undesirable, because I need replica set for several operations, and embedded replica set startup/initialization takes about thirty seconds for each set of tests.)

Comment: You might want to try load() - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/, or perhaps do a mongodump/mongorestore approach.

Comment: @barrypicker  `load()` is a native method, couldn't find it in mongodb java driver. For load or dumping I'd require to have mongo bin utility installed on agent that run tests?
Not very convenient :/